# Unable to assign value in variable of Structure in C using Pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, structure

My Code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Demo{
    int value;
};
int main(){
    struct Demo *l;
    l->value=4;
}
```

Getting Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Of course, `l` is not pointing to any valid object, so whose `.value` are you expecting to assign to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because L object doesn't point something.
use this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Demo
{
    int val;    
};
int main()
{
    Demo* a = new Demo();
    a->val = 10;
    cout<<a->val;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory to `l` Demo object. In `C` you have to allocate memory using `malloc`. See the code for a better understanding.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct Demo{
    int value;
};

int main(){
    struct Demo *l = (struct Demo*)malloc(sizeof (struct Demo));
    l->value = 4;
    printf("%d\n", l->value);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
4
```